# How can I remove outliers from my dataset?

Tags: python, outliers

[Hi
I am working on a dataset in name hi_1_df. When I plotted a column based the other one (Capacity per Cycle number) unfortunately I faced to lots of outliers and I can't remove them. I tried some ways but they didn't result. One approach that suggested to me was using polynomial fit function and then remove the outliers but I cant How should I implement it in python ?
I need help to delete the outliers][image](http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/New%20Cs2%20Data/All_Cell_CS2/First%20work%20with%20cs2_35%20data%20(use%20voltage%20as%20features).ipynb)

```
x = hi_1_df['Cycle_Number']
y = hi_1_df['Capacity']

plt.scatter(x, y, label='Original Data', s=10)
plt.title('Main plot of Capacity Variation')
plt.xlabel('Cycle Number')
plt.ylabel('Capacity')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.boxplot(y)
plt.xlabel('Capacity')
plt.title('Box Plot of Capacity')
plt.show()

# Fit a polynomial to my data
degree = 10
coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)

# Create a new x-axis range for the smoothed curve
x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)

# Calculate the corresponding y values using the polynomial
y_smooth = poly(x_smooth)

# Plot the original data and the smoothed curve
plt.title('eliminated out layers and smoothing plot')
plt.scatter(x, y, label='Original Data', s=10)
plt.plot(x_smooth, y_smooth, 'r', label='Smoothed Curve')

plt.xlabel('Cycle Number')
plt.ylabel('Capacity')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With sample `df`